# How to get street name from latitude and longitude?

Tags: android, google-maps

I tried to use geocoder.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getAddressLine(int)
It helps to find common information but is useless for name of the street and number of building.
How can I get it from latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Location gpsLocation = appLocationService
                            .getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (gpsLocation != null) {
                        double latitude = gpsLocation.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = gpsLocation.getLongitude();
                        String result = "Latitude: " + gpsLocation.getLatitude() +
                                " Longitude: " + gpsLocation.getLongitude();
                        tvAddress.setText(result);
                    }
```

Hope it will work

Thankew! Happy coding!

Comment: no, sorry. I try to take name of place from lattitude and longtitude, not vice versa